# document.documentElement.scrollHeight does not update correctly inside a function in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, dom

I have a long list of json items. I am trying to append them to a div. After appending a single item, I call a function that checks the value of document.documentElement.scrollHeight. But this function does not give me correct value on subsequent calls as the list increases and browser shows a scroll bar.
I am following this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-asynchronous-infinite-scroll-with-vue-watchers

```
//this function is inside the methods:  of Vuejs
function isBottomReached(){
  //Use document.documentElement.scrollHeight here to return a boolean value.
}
var bigListofItems = [];//an array with lots of objects in it.

//loop over the list and show items based on the val of isBottomReached()
//this logic is inside the created() hook of Vue
if(this.isBottomReached()){
     //append to DOM
}
```

I expect that whenever isBottomReached() function is called it should give me the scrollHeight of the browser at that exact point in time.

Comment: How are you modifying the DOM? If you're modifying the DOM directly then the scroll height should be updated immediately; otherwise if you're appending the item to an array which is rendered by Vue then Vue will update the DOM asynchronously and the scroll height won't have updated as soon as you append to the array. You will need to use [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to schedule code to be executed after Vue has patched the DOM and the scroll height will be updated.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I am currently appending to an Array. I will try with nextTick. Thanks.

Comment: Read [Async Update Queue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue) in the docs for a full explanation.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Hey thanks ... It is showing the correct value of scrollHeight now. Thanks a lot. Can you post as an answer so i can mark it closed?